# \cal messes up the math mode

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode, mathcal

How come when I use this code with `beamer`

```
\begin{block}{Misadjustment}
 $$ \cal{M} = \frac{1-\lambda}{2}\sigma_v^2 M + \frac{1}{2(1-\lambda)}tr[\mathbf{RQ}] $$
\end{block}
```

results in this:

[image]

But when I remove the `\cal`, the equation is displayed correctly.

Comment: \cal is a font, so you can also write your equation with $${\cal M}=\frac{1-\lambda}{2} ...$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `\mathcal`, which takes an argument, not `\cal`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Misadjustment}
\[
  \mathcal{M} = \frac{1-\lambda}{2}\sigma_v^2 M + \frac{1}{2(1-\lambda)}tr[\mathbf{RQ}]
\]
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The use is similar to your font switching macro `\mathbf`. Also note the use of `\[`...`\]` to denote a display math equation rather than the TeX `$$`...`$$` notation. For more on this, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764).